# Declare Static var in SwiftUI #Preview macro

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-previews

I have the following code in SwiftUI preview macro.

```
  #Preview {
     @StateObject static var store = Store()
     ...
  }
```

And it fails with the error:

> Static properties may only be declared on a type

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Static for a StateObject doesn’t quite make sense. States object should be inside a View.

Comment: I need to use the same `store` variable in all previews. Anyway to achieve that?

Comment: I prefer Dependency Injection so you can mock easily. There are many different ways like creating wrappers or view modifiers

Comment: "I need to use the same store variable in all previews" doesn't make a lot of sense. Your app is going to be restarted "under the covers" when you make code changes, so `store` will continually be recreated anyway, even if it  were a static. Why do you think you need a static for previews?

Comment: @Paulw11 You are right, this is what I thought as well. But Apple's SKDemo sample code uses the same static var in Previews, though it uses older previewProvider than the macro `#Preview`.

Comment: Yes. Their static properties are on the preview provider struct. You can use that code if you like instead of the preview macro.